# ProfilePropertyLoader Properties

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

In SharePoint **.aspx** page I can write the below code, I need to know the all the available properties of `ProfilePropertyValue` other then `AccountName`.

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue runat="server" id="UserName" PropertyName="AccountName" />
```

I could not find a reference that list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for properties of the `ProfilePropertyValue` control, have a look at [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms549807(v%3Doffice.15)). As for User Profile properties that are available by default, you can have a look at these articles (although the latter might be incomplete as its for SP2010):

1. https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/default-user-profile-properties/
2. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-online-177eb196-5887-43c9-84c3-b98a43d35129